# Header Files and Libraries

Tags: c, static-libraries, header-files

Do I really need header files for using libraries?My code works without header files and the libraries are linked perfectly except that I get a "warning: implicit declaration of function"
message.Still its just a warning my program runs.

Comment: Do you like bugs in your programs?  Or are you such a good programmer that you never make a mistake or misuse a function?  Do you get warnings about `printf()` not declared? You invoke undefined behaviour if you don't declare it properly? If you were such a good programmer, you wouldn't be asking the question, so the answer is "Yes, you do need the headers, because you're a mortal like the rest of us".  Also, C99 requires functions to be declared before they are used — so your code can only be compatible with the ancient C89 standard, not with the C99 (old standard) of C11 (current standard).

Comment: Never say "just a warning" - a warning that you choose to ignore could result in a bug that takes hours to find later.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think OP is looking for the word "humility". Few people are smarter than the creators of C.

Comment: You've got a loaded gun in your hands and you are aiming it at your foot.  It *will* fire sometimes, you'll be hopping around for a while.  This has to be learned the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

[Header file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_file):- is a file that allows programmers to separate certain elements of a program's source code into reusable files.

A library file is the executable code that works according to what is specified in the header file.

> I get a "warning: implicit declaration of function" message.

There may be many reasons for this warning like maybe your header guard is not working right. Another possibility is that you have declared the function `Func` but called it with `func`.

Check [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_header_files.htm) out:-

> Including a header file is equal to copying the content of the header
>   file but we do not do it because it will be very much error-prone and
>   it is not a good idea to copy the content of header file in the source
>   files, specially if we have multiple source file comprising our
>   program.

Answer (score 1):

For most of the starters this warning is seen when they start using

```
malloc
```

So I am using this example. For the warning in this case You need to add:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

This file includes the declaration for the built-in function `malloc`. If you don't do that, the compiler thinks you want to define your own function named `malloc` and it warns you because:

1. You don't explicitly declare it *and*
2. There already is a built-in function by that name which has a different signature than the one that was implicitly declared (when a function is declared implicitly, its return and argument types are assumed to be `int`, which isn't compatible with the built-in `malloc`, which takes a `size_t` and returns a `void*`).

Answer (score 1):

> My code works without header files and the libraries are linked
>   perfectly except that I get a "warning: implicit declaration of
>   function" message.Still its just a warning my program runs.

It is a bad practice to ignore a warning from the compiler. Programs that are not compiled properly could have bugs that might cause you bigger problems and errors in the future.

So for example, if you get a warning:

```
prog.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of /*some function used in the program*/
```

It is expected that you must include the header file wherein that function is defined.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I really need header files for using libraries?

Yes.

> My code works without header files

No, it doesn't. It only appears to be working.

> and the libraries are linked perfectly except that I get a "warning: implicit declaration of function" message

In this case, I wouldn't call it "perfect".

> Still its just a warning my program runs.

And you can never know what it does since **it now invokes undefined behavior.** "Just a warning"? Sure. There's a reason the compiler warns you. **Respect warnings and fix them.**

Here's the quote from C99 (6.5.2.2.6) which explains why the program has UB without headers (more precisely, without proper function prototypes which you don't seem to have either):

> 1. If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a prototype, the integer promotions are performed on each argument, and arguments that have type float are promoted to double. These are called the default argument promotions. **If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the behavior is undefined.**
>
> **If** the function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either the prototype ends with an ellipsis (, ...) or **the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with the types of the parameters, the behavior is undefined.**
>
> **If** the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and **the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior is undefined,** except for the following cases:
>
> — one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the
>   corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;
>
> — both types are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of a character type or
>   void.

There's a very good reason header files are used. People who invented and designed the language knew what they were doing, and they made this decision because it's a necessary thing and a good solution to the problem that types need to be visible across compilation units.